# Python: fit two dependent functions

Tags: python, vector, scipy, curve-fitting

I have the two following functions:

```
d_out = foc+(d_in-foc)/(((d_in)/foc-1.0)**(2)+(zR/foc)**(2))

w_out = w0*np.sqrt(1.0/(((d_in)/foc-1.0)**(2)+(zR/foc)**(2)))
```

And I want to calculate (fit) the parameter `foc` for given parameters `d_out, w_out, zR, w0.` The parameter `d_in` can have values between 10-100.

For both functions, the same `foc` should be fitted and I don't know how to do this. Maybe as a vector? I am not a pro with Python.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please add a small data set with five or six data points? I can post an example using your equations, and you could then substitute the entire data set and have a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```
d_out= 109.39
w_out= 4.98
zR= 13.73
w0= 2.7
d_in= 10-100
```